# SyntaxError in Pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, syntax-error

*When I save on Sublime text and refresh localhost:3000, I keep getting this error. What should I do?

---

Showing /Users/Matt/code/omrails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line **#21** raised:

```
/Users/Matt/code/omrails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
/Users/Matt/code/omrails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Extracted source (around line **#21**):

```
18:         </div>
19:     </body>
20: </html>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

---

This is what my *application.html.erb* file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>One Month Rails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render "layouts/header" %>

    <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
        <%= yield %>

        <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

## What did I do wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `end` for `flash.each do`

I.e right view is next

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>One Month Rails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render "layouts/header" %>

    <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>

        <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Simply posting some code without any explanation is not very useful, please improve your answer.